# R: Storing different sized matrices in the same array

Tags: arrays, r, data-structures

I'm sifting through a data set, and grouping certain rows together. The data set is 18 rows by 8 columns. It contains both numerical and word info. My method is as follows: If the first 5 columns of a row are the same as another row, I want group those two rows together in a matrix.

Here is my my issue:

- I do not know how many rows will be the same (therefore, when I create a matrix of the rows I won't know its dimensions). I have concluded that I need an array that can store different sized matrices. Is this possible? If not, how would you recommend I store the rows?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you just want a proper `list` of matrices. But your description of what you're doing is pretty non-specific. It's difficult to make an exact recommendation. How about sharing some sample data and code.

Comment: Go with list to store.